# injecting code into ruby state-machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I would like to monkey-patch the pluginaweek state machine (https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) so that I can inject code into a state machine from a mixin module.  Does anyone know how to define a new method in state machine to do this?  Or, perhaps there is a better way of doing what I want to accomplish?

Hypothetically,

```
class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Provisionable # << This module makes the magic method 'provision',
                        # << below, available

  state_machine :machine_state, :initial => :s_initial do
    # ...
    provision(:param1, :param2, :param3) # << The Question: how to define
                                         # << this in the Provisionable mixin
                                         # << module, below
    ...
  end
...
end

module Provisionable
  #
  # << provision() is supposed to inject the desired code into the state machine:
  #
  def provision

    # << Code sample to be injected begins here:
    event :parameterize do
      transition :s_unprovisioned => :s_initial
    end
    before_transition :s_unprovisioned => :s_initial do |artifact, transition|
      transition.args.each_pair do |param, value|
        # etc...
      end
    end
    # >> Code to be injected ends here.

  end
end
```

For those shopping for a state machine, I highly recommend this one.

Thanks!

[Added later:]  I worked out a solution, which I hope will be helpful to others.  Instead of mixing in a module, I monkey patched state_machine to add instance methods to inject code.

```
StateMachine::Machine.class_eval do
    def inject_provisioning()

        event :start do
            transition :s_initial => :s_provisioning
        end
        after_transition :s_initial => :s_provisioning do |goal, transition|
            # Do useful stuff here
            true
        end

        event :provision do
            transition :s_provisioning => :s_completed
        end

        before_transition :s_provisioning => :s_completed do |goal, transition|
            artifact_type = transition.args[0]
            params = transition.args[1]
            # Useful stuff here
            true
        end

        after_transition :s_provisioning => :s_completed do |goal, transition|
            artifact_type = transition.args[0]
            params = transition.args[1]
            # Useful stuff here
        end
    end

    def inject_expiration()
        event :chron do
            expired_callback = lambda \
                do |goal|
                    return false if goal.expires_at == :never
                    goal.expires_at.to_i < DateTime.now.to_i
                end
            active_callback = lambda \
                do |goal|
                    return true if goal.expires_at == :never
                    goal.expires_at.to_i >= DateTime.now.to_i
                end
            transition all - :s_expired => :s_expired, :if => expired_callback
        end

        before_transition all - :s_expired => :s_expired do |goal, transition|
            goal.undo
        end
    end
```

Now when I have a state_machine definition open in a class, I can make simple macro-like calls to inject code:

```
state_machine :machine_state, :initial => :s_initial do
    inject_provisioning
    inject_expiration
end
```

Hope someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do but hopefully this code will help

```
class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Provision

  attr_accessible :some_value, :state

  state_machine :state, :initial => :initial do
    event :foo do
      transition :initial => :bar
    end

    Artifact.provision(self, :param1, :param2, :param3)

    event :fud do
      transition :bar => :initial
    end

  end
end
```

note - we are mixing in using `extend` instead of `include` - that puts the methods at the class level instead of the instance, pass `self` (which is the state machine) to the method

```
module Provision
  def provision(state_machine, *args)

    state_machine do
      event :provision do
        transition :initial => :provisioned
      end

      event :deprovision do
        transition :provisioned => :deprovisioned
      end

      before_transition :provisioned => :deprovisioned do |item, transition|
        # transition.args.length == 0
        args.each do |arg|
          puts arg
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Hi house9, thanks for your solution.  I ended up monkey patching in new instance methods to state_machine, which turned out to be pretty straight-forward.